# Read Access Violation From Using Smart Pointers

Tags: c++

This problem has bugged me for several days now, and I just cant figure it out. What I am trying to do is get an Entity from the entityMap and make a copy of it. An Entity is essentialy a map of components, so I looped through each component and made a copy of it. I debugged the program, and it worked fine until the very last line, where it said "read access violation **this** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7." It was very strange as everything was initialized (I checked the debugger)

```
if (entityMap.find(classname) != entityMap.end()) {
    std::shared_ptr<Entity> & prefab = entityMap[classname];
    std::shared_ptr<Entity> entity = std::shared_ptr<Entity>(new Entity());
    for (auto & component : prefab->GetComponentMap()) {
        Component * compPtr = component.second.get();
        std::cout << compPtr->GetMemorySize() << "\n";
        size_t size = sizeof(compPtr->GetMemorySize());
        void * buffer = operator new(size);
        memcpy(buffer, compPtr, size);
        std::shared_ptr<Component> newComponent = std::shared_ptr<Component>(reinterpret_cast<Component *>(buffer));
        entity->AddComponent(newComponent);
        newComponent->SetOwner(entity);
    }
```

Here is the offending line

```
 newComponent->SetOwner(entity);
```

Here is all it does, setting the owner instance variable to the passed in parameter. That was where the debugger complained and sent me to file "memory" at _Decref method.

```
void Component::SetOwner(std::shared_ptr<Entity> owner) {
    this->owner = owner;
}
```

Comment: In general you can’t just memcpy objects. What is `Component` exactly? What does `GetMemorySize` do? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: why not `newComponnent = std::make_shared<Component>(comptr);`  seems unnecessary to create a buffer and do memcpy when you could do a copy in the constructor of Component instead. It is preferable to avoid void* in C++.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Component is a base class, so I actually do not know the type I was making so i couldnt just do a copy constructor. GetMemorySize() method is used to get the size of the object I need to copy

Comment: You’ll need to have a proper way of cloning objects, in the objects. Never do this. If the objects are anything else than just plain data this will blow up, as it did.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thank you very much. I took your advice and it works. Turn out it is not because of smart pointers after all. If you would make an answer, I can approve it and close the thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you can’t copy objects just by copying the memory. For basic plain data objects without any constructors, destructors, or pointers this *may* work but for anything more complex it most likely won’t.

For example, if the object contains pointers to data and these are released in a destructor then the data is not deep copied, rather the pointer is, and you get double free and also possible pointers to unallocated memory. If the object relies on something being done in the constructor it is never done when copying memory. And depending on how the size is calculated it may not even be a complete copy.

This is why you should always provide a cloning mechanism in the class that takes care of these issues in a way that suits the object and makes sure there’s proper deep/shallow copying depending on the contents.